# Restarting a service from a script

Tags: bash, init-script

I have a *init script* - `/etc/init.d/myservice`, which starts some processes, including  a **CLI process**. And from this CLI process, I am adding a *command* which can be used to restart the service (restart *ourselves* - kind of).

What I tried - from a script (that is spawned from the CLI command), ran `sudo service myservice restart`, where `restart` is `stop;start`.
But, this doesn't work! i.e, even though the `stop` happens, by the time `start` part is executing, the script terminates (not with any signals, but plain `EXIT`).

I tried combinations of `nohup`, `disown` etc, but didn't seem to work! I am not sure how to complete the `restart` without getting terminated - any pointers, or workarounds to debug further ?

To summarize:

- `myservice` -> spawns many processes, including **CLI**
- CLI -> has a `restart` command, which invokes a *script*
- *script* does `sudo service myservice restart`

--More info--

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, i.e, `upstart`

Comment: What's the OS, init system (upstart, systemd, sysvinit...)?

Comment: How is the "stop" action done? Does it help if you add a `trap '' TERM` in your _restart_ script?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas added more info, `stop` does a usual `kill` by process name. If I add `trap..TERM` wouldn't it affect other ways of start/stop - like, from shell if one does `sudo myservice stop` ?

Comment: would your _kill by process name_ (it's better to combine that with pid files to avoid problems or use cgroups as systemd) not possibly kill your script?

Comment: I don't understand _cgroups as systemd_ :(. The script _name_ is not in the list of processes to be stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I had searched for quite some time, but I found one solution here to this SuperUser Q&A titled: [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely/178589#178589), after posting my question here.

```
| at now
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the service again you might want to wait for a few seconds so that it stops properly. You can delay your script with the following line

```
# waiting for 5 seconds
sleep 5
```

You can see more details here - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/

Comment: the `stop` is happening, but at `start` the script terminates.